# Using absolute path to import a json from the same module throws eslint error (import/no-extraneous-dependencies) in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, json, import, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

I am doing an absolute import for the json file that is inside the module called @myproject/module1 but it is throwing the following error  :

```
'@myproject/module1' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S @myproject/module1' to add it  import/no-extraneous-dependencies
```

But my other .ts, .tsx files are imported successfully with absolute import
Eg imports:

```
1) import Button from "@myproject/module1/src/components/button/Button";
2) import Json from "@myproject/module1/src/sample/sample.json";
```

1st line works as expected but the second line throws the above eslint error.

***Note*:*** I **do not** want to **turn off** `import/no-extraneous-dependencies` rule in eslint.

Thanks in advance.